# WPF Drag and Drop with Adorner using mouse and touch

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, multi-touch

I want this to be good question, so I'll write in details what I would like to achieve, what I've found on the internet and I show what I've done so far and what I've tried.

I need to add drag and drop functionality to my application. I have Images (basically controls) that I want to drag to items of listbox.

Here is sample UI:

[image]

And here is usage I have now:

[image]

As You can see I'm able to drag one of four images and drop it over listbox item.
If I move image over correct target (listbox image) image near cursor disappears and everything works fine, but when I don't drop image on list item (I release mouse) that image stays on screen.

I've based my solution on answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129443/wpf-4-drag-and-drop-with-visual-element-as-cursor) question, and I'm unable to remove that unwanted window (image near cursor)

My XAML looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="DragDrop.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Drag'n'Drop" Height="350" Width="525"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Right" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Height="300" Margin="0,10,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="234" ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" AllowDrop="True" PreviewDrop="UIElement_OnPreviewDrop">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                        <ProgressBar Height="20" Value="{Binding Points}" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="72" Source="Images/coins-60000-icon.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
               PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="OnMouseTouchDown"
               PreviewTouchDown="OnMouseTouchDown"
               PreviewGiveFeedback="UIElement_OnPreviewGiveFeedback" Tag="10"/>
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" Margin="87,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="72" Source="Images/coins-700000-icon.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
               PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="OnMouseTouchDown"
               PreviewTouchDown="OnMouseTouchDown"
               PreviewGiveFeedback="UIElement_OnPreviewGiveFeedback" Tag="20"/>
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" Margin="10,87,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="72" Source="Images/coins-7000-icon.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
               PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="OnMouseTouchDown"
               PreviewTouchDown="OnMouseTouchDown"
               PreviewGiveFeedback="UIElement_OnPreviewGiveFeedback" Tag="30"/>
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" Margin="87,87,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="72" Source="Images/coins-700-icon.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
               PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="OnMouseTouchDown"
               PreviewTouchDown="OnMouseTouchDown"
               PreviewGiveFeedback="UIElement_OnPreviewGiveFeedback" Tag="40"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<Person> _people = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

    public ObservableCollection<Person> People
    {
        get { return _people; }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _people.Add(new Person() {Name = "Person1", Points = 10});
        _people.Add(new Person() {Name = "Person2", Points = 0});
        _people.Add(new Person() {Name = "Person3", Points = 40});
    }

    private void OnMouseTouchDown(object sender, InputEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = sender as Image;
        if (item == null) return;

        var draggedItem = item;
        var points = Convert.ToInt32(draggedItem.Tag);
        CreateDragDropWindow(draggedItem);
        System.Windows.DragDrop.DoDragDrop(draggedItem, points, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }

    private Window _dragdropWindow;

    private void CreateDragDropWindow(Visual dragElement)
    {
        _dragdropWindow = new Window
        {
            WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None,
            AllowsTransparency = true,
            AllowDrop = false,
            Background = null,
            IsHitTestVisible = false,
            SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight,
            Topmost = true,
            ShowInTaskbar = false
        };

        Rectangle r = new Rectangle
        {
            Width = ((FrameworkElement) dragElement).ActualWidth/2,
            Height = ((FrameworkElement) dragElement).ActualHeight/2,
            Fill = new VisualBrush(dragElement)
        };
        _dragdropWindow.Content = r;


        Win32Point w32Mouse = new Win32Point();
        GetCursorPos(ref w32Mouse);


        _dragdropWindow.Left = w32Mouse.X;
        _dragdropWindow.Top = w32Mouse.Y;
        _dragdropWindow.Show();
    }


    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref Win32Point pt);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct Win32Point
    {
        public Int32 X;
        public Int32 Y;
    };

    private void UIElement_OnPreviewGiveFeedback(object sender, GiveFeedbackEventArgs e)
    {
        Win32Point w32Mouse = new Win32Point();
        GetCursorPos(ref w32Mouse);

        _dragdropWindow.Left = w32Mouse.X;
        _dragdropWindow.Top = w32Mouse.Y;
    }

    private void UIElement_OnPreviewDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        //var droppedData = e.Data.GetData(typeof(Image)) as Image;
        var droppedData = (Int32) e.Data.GetData(typeof (Int32));
        var stackPanel = sender as StackPanel;
        if (stackPanel != null)
        {
            var student = stackPanel.DataContext as Person;

            //int targetIndex = _people.IndexOf(student);


            if (student != null) student.Points += droppedData;
        }
        if (_dragdropWindow != null)
        {
            _dragdropWindow.Close();
            _dragdropWindow = null;
        }
    }
}

public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    private int _points;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _name) return;
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int Points
    {
        get { return _points; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _points) return;
            _points = value;
            if (_points >= 100)
            {
                _points -= 100;
                Debug.WriteLine("100!");
            }
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

I found over the internet that I can use class that extends Adorner and I found some examples:

- http://nonocast.cn/adorner-in-wpf-part-5-drag-and-drop/ - (WaybackMachine archive [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20131015000055/http://nonocast.cn/adorner-in-wpf-part-5-drag-and-drop/))
- http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/488#.VfiMSBHtmko
- http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/alex_fidanov/archive/2009/07/28/drag-amp-drop-with-datapresenter-family-controls.aspx
- https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop

but all of them show how to drag items from collections (ItemsControls). Third link was promising, but I wasn't able to adopt it to my needs.

So my questions are:

1. How can I hide that small image window in my example when I cancel drag (MouseUp or incorrect drag target)
2. Show I use Adorner and how can I use it in my code? I need to show it when I start drag and hide when I drop Image correctly or I cancel drag or drop target is incorrect

I'm starting with WPF so please try to understand my frustration - I've spend last two evenings and night trying to get this working.

Comment: I have create adorner window like your solution. But the adorner window is not placed near the mouse pointer when dragging. Please give any suggestion to do this. Also I have referred your link you mentioned in your question. But it is not helps me.

Comment: @Achu_L maybe You calculate _dragdropWindow position wrong. Change it style to not be transparent and then see how it looks/works. I can't say much without seeing the code.

Comment: Please kindly refer my sample project from the below mentioned link. https://drive.google.com/open?id=17CNm2nKQ8-801Advc8yEfG-oGbSwZdeh

Comment: @Achu_L I don't see any problems. I'm able to drag Items from the list and they appear on the bottom right of the cursor (when dragging).

Comment: When dragging the adorner window is takes some distance from the mouse pointer. But I want to place the adorner window very close to mouse pointer when dragging.

Comment: Please give your valuable suggestion to done this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Modify your OnMouseTouchDown handler to include assigning ContinueDragHandler to dragged item before starting the drag, like this

```
 private void OnMouseTouchDown(object sender, InputEventArgs e)
        {
            var item = sender as FrameworkElement;
            if (item == null) return;

            var draggedItem = item;
            var points = Convert.ToInt32(draggedItem.Tag);
            CreateDragDropWindow(draggedItem);
            System.Windows.DragDrop.AddQueryContinueDragHandler(draggedItem, DragContrinueHandler);
            System.Windows.DragDrop.DoDragDrop(draggedItem, points, DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
```

And the handler itself:

```
public void DragContrinueHandler(object sender, QueryContinueDragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Action == DragAction.Continue && e.KeyStates != DragDropKeyStates.LeftMouseButton)
            {
                _dragdropWindow.Close();
            }
        }
```

2) I believe that creating a new window to display image next to a cursor is a dirty dirty hack. There are plenty of various articles around about using adorners with drag'n'drop. Althought your approach works and doesn't require a lot of code. Adorners do, on the other hand. I think you should create another question, if you fail following certain tutorial, with code examples and what steps you took

Comment: I'm sorry I can't say anything about touch. Never worked with it.

Comment: Thank You so much for help, I'll check that solution after I'll get back home. I had problem with Adorners, because they work with Mouse and I need touch support. MouseEventArgs have GetPosition method, howerev InputEventArgs don't. Any advice on how to create touch friendly Adorners is more than welcome :)

Comment: Works perfect :) Thank You!

Comment: UIElement_OnPreviewDrop is not firing on drop